# The others, who is dead or who is alive?

Tags: the-others

In the movie The Others, 
whose family is dead and whose is alive? Victor's family or Nicolas' family?
Who is Lydia and old couples?

Answer (score 11):

Grace and the 2 children, Anne and Nicholas, are dead and ghosts, but they don't know they are until they found out at the end of the movie. Her husband is also dead; he was killed in the war. Grace killed her children when she was psychotic and then killed herself.

The 3 servants (Mrs. Mills, Tuttle the gardener and Lydia) are also ghosts but they know. They died of tuberculosis 50 years earlier.

Victor and his parents are alive. They are trying to buy the house but discover it is haunted by ghosts. The old woman is a medium who is holding a seance with Victor's family to get rid of the ghosts, which they fail to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the end , it is revealed that Nicolas family is dead and Victor's family is alive.

That's is the whole twist of movie, that they are not aware that they are dead and they think others as dead.

Refer [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Others_(2001_film)#Plot)